# TinyXML #include problem... Using libraries

Tags: c++, terminal, textmate, libraries, tinyxml

Hey, i'm really trying to get TinyXML to at least read a file but it says "main.cpp:8: error: ‘TiXMLDocument’ was not declared in this scope"

This is the code im using:

```
TiXMLDocument("demo.xml");
```

Ideally i want to read able to read files and output the XML so i also tried this code i found online in a tutorial

```
#include <iostream>

#include "tinyxml.h"
#include "tinystr.h"

void dump_to_stdout(const char* pFilename)
{
    TiXmlDocument doc(pFilename);
    bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
    if (loadOkay)
    {
        printf("\n%s:\n", pFilename);
        dump_to_stdout( &doc ); // defined later in the tutorial
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to load file \"%s\"\n", pFilename);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    dump_to_stdout("demo.xml");
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors I'm getting now are:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void dump_to_stdout(const char*)’:
main.cpp:13: error: cannot convert ‘TiXmlDocument*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void dump_to_stdout(const char*)’
```

If it helps im on a mac, ive tried compiling in terminal as well as textmate. I also tried to compile the cpp files for TinyXML separately before compiling main.cpp and i have no idea why i cant print out demo.xml let alone read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's called [`TiXmlDocument`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html), not `TiXMLDocument`
2. You can't call a function that you haven't declared yet. Since you're trying to call an undeclared overload of `dump_to_stdout`, the compiler assumes you want to call the version that takes `const char *` and fails.

Comment: sorry, was working on the second lot of code... but i tried changing to TiXmlDocument and still didn't work. Undefined symbols:
  "TiXmlNode::~TiXmlNode()", referenced from:
      TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()in ccfppiJ4.o
  "vtable for TiXmlDocument", referenced from:
      TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()in ccfppiJ4.o
  "TiXmlString::nullrep_", referenced from:
      TiXmlString::quit()      in ccfppiJ4.o
  "TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccfppiJ4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @CurtisJC: that's a linker error. Are you linking with `-ltinyxml`?

Comment: @AFAIK, I've never used tinyxml has a lib.  I've always just had to include the source files in my project.  It's my understanding that's how they've always been distributed.  Could that be the issue here?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, @CurtisJC: TinyXML is distributed as a shared library on some Linux platforms, including Debian and Ubuntu. Otherwise, Curtis forgot to link in the object files.

Comment: i just have all the files in the same folder.. so i think this must be the problem... how do i link them? and im guessing i have to link with main.cpp aswell?

Comment: When you've compiled the all files (with `gcc -c`), run `gcc` with all the resulting `.o` files. See the GCC manual for details.

Comment: ok... as im working with c++ ive been using g++ as opposed to gcc, but tried that anyways... in terminal <code>g++ -c tinystr.cpp tinyxml.cpp</code> which gave me .o files, after that in terminal <code>g++ tinystr.o tinyxml.o main.cpp</code> and im getting "undefined symbols" when it trys to compile

Comment: @CurtisJC, yes, `g++`, sorry. Which symbols are undefined?

Comment: attempted a copy paste but too bulky.. Undefined symbols:
  "vtable for TiXmlDocument", referenced from:
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument(char const*)in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument()in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument()in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument(char const*)in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument(TiXmlDocument const&)in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument(TiXmlDocument const&)in tinyxml.o
      TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()in cclsRFr7.o
  "TiXmlDocument::SetError(int, char const*, TiXmlParsingData*, TiXmlEncoding)", etc...

Comment: @larsmans Ok was definitely a link problem... finally figured out how im supposed to run it, textmate is not good for linking cpp files apparently... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
dump_to_stdout( &doc ); // defined later in the tutorial
```

Here's your problem.

1. `dump_to_stdout` takes a `const char*` which TiXmlDocument is definitely not.
2. You're already *in* that function, so assuming the file loads you'll have infinite recursion.
3. It doesn't matter that you've got one defined later that takes a TiXmlDocument.  At this point, the only `dump_to_stdout` that exists is the one you're in, hence the error.  Forward declare the one you want before this function, e.g:   `void dump_to_stdout(TiXmlDocument*);`

Comment: The compiler error clearly shows that no infinite recursion is taking place. It just won't compile.

Comment: @larsmans, I am aware of that.  I am just pointing out that if that did resolve (if the document had a const char* operator, for example), that it would recurse.  It certainly doesn't form the basis of my suggestions.

Comment: all your other suggestions are entirely correct. However, C++'s overloading resolution will prevent infinite recursion unless `dump_to_stdout(TiXmlDocument*)` calls back into `dump_to_stdout(const char *)`.